# bash, copy files listed in a text file one by one

Tags: whitespace, bash

```
#!/bin/sh

ls|cat > temp       #WRITE CONTENTS OF CURRENT DIRECTORY INTO temp FILE

LENGTH=$(wc -l temp)    #TO MONITOR EOF

echo "there are ${LENGTH% *} files/directories present"

COUNT=1         #INITIALIZE COUNTER BY ONE

CONTENT=$(head -$COUNT temp|tail -1)    #STORE COUNTth NAME INTO CONTENT

echo $CONTENT|sed s/' '/'\\'/g

mv `echo $CONTENT|sed s/' '/'\\'/g` virtual/
```

The intention is to write the output of the `ls` command to a temp file, pick a file name one by one from the temp file, and copy them to respective location.

The problem is, when I use "CONTENT" as an argument to the `cp` command, suppose $CONTENT is "hello world", `cp` treat it as two separate files "hello" and "world".

Need help.

Comment: In bash, use `${CONTENT// /\\}` instead of piping the output through `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always wrap shell variables in quotes when you use them as parameters to a command.  This solves the space problem you encountered and helps protect against malicious input.

```
echo "$CONTENT"
```